# Getting Terraform error: "Error: expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got: with err: invalid CIDR address:"

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to make a simple vpc/security group module set. VPC resource is here:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.cidr
}
```

Security Group resources are here:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "default" {
  name        = var.sg-name
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id
  description = var.sg-description
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress" {
  count = length(var.allowed_ip)

  type = "ingress"
  from_port = element(var.allowed_ports, count.index)
  to_port = element(var.allowed_ports, count.index)
  protocol = var.protocol
  cidr_blocks = var.allowed_ip
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.default.id
}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  type              = "egress"
  from_port         = 0
  to_port           = 65535
  protocol          = "-1"
  cidr_blocks       = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.default.id
}
```

Modules are here:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../"

  cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
}

module "security_group" {
  source = "../"

  sg-name = "Test"
  sg-description = "Test Description"

  protocol = "tcp"
  allowed_ip = ["10.10.0.0/20", "10.20.0.0/20"]
  allowed_ports = [22, 443]
}
```

When I run Terraform Plan, I get this error:

> Error: expected cidr_block to contain a valid Value, got:  with err:
> invalid CIDR address:
>
> on ..\vpc.tf line 2, in resource "aws_vpc" "main":    2:
> cidr_block = var.cidr

I've done a lot of researching but can't quite nail the issue. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I think there is something odd with your directory structure. Are those dir paths on your sources correct?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a variable but you don't have a variables.tf, you are specifying the cidr block on a resource, so, it should look something like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = module.vpc.cidr
}
```

Otherwise, you can create a variables.tf where you have something like this (which is the way it is usually done, but also we tend to pass these values through a file with the extension ".tfvars"):

```
variable "cidr" {
   cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
}
```

Once you have defined variables, you can use the format "var.variable".